# Как копировать файлы с заменой в Linux тем же методом, что и в Windows? (без учёта регистра)

Tags: linux

У меня есть Morrowind и куча модов к нему. Я хочу эти моды установить. Как вам известно, Morrowind писался под винду и моды к нему соответственно тоже, но я использую кроссплатформенный движок OpenMW, что позволяет нативно запускать игру в линуксе.

Так вот в чём моя проблема: установка модов обычно сводится к распаковке файлов из архива мода в директорию игры с заменой. Беда в том, что если оригинальная папка называется "Sound", а в архиве находится папка "sound", то никакой замены не произойдёт (аналогично и с файлами)! У меня просто будет 2 разных папки/файла, потому что линукс чувствителен к регистру. В итоге мод установится криво (а таких модов очень много и вручную я всё проследить не могу).

Comment: Я бы пошла другим путем. Код распаковщика например на `perl` или `python` с использованием стандартных библиотек, который будет приводить все имена распаковываемых файлов к общему стандарту, займет меньше 20 строк.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

специализированного средства для исправления подобной эксклюзивной «кривизны», конечно, нет.

но такое средство несложно написать на любом подходящем языке программирования, или даже обойтись оболочкой и утилитами из *gnu/coreutils*.

---

например, у нас есть «базовый» каталог `1`:

```
$ tree 1
1
└── Sound
    ├── File
    └── File2
```

и есть распакованный (или любым другим образом полученный) каталог `2`, в котором есть некоторые файлы/каталоги, отличающиеся от аналогичных файлов/каталогов из каталога `1` регистром имени:

```
$ tree 2
2
└── sound
    ├── file
    └── file3
```

фактически, нам надо привести имена таких файлов/каталогов к тому же регистру, что и в каталоге `1`. т.е., `sound/file` переименовать в `sound/File` и `sound` переименовать в `Sound`.

1. сохраним имя «базового» каталога в переменной `base`, а имя «переименовываемого» каталога — в `ren`:

   ```
   $ base=1 ren=2
   ```
2. составим список файлов/каталогов, совпадающих при преобразовании их в нижний регистр (с таким же успехом можно было и в верхний):

   ```
   $ comm -1 -2 \
   <(cd "$base"; find -mindepth 1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort) \
   <(cd "$ren"; find -mindepth 1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort)
   ```

   получаем:

   ```
   ./sound
   ./sound/file
   ```
3. в цикле будем читать имена, находить исходные (без преобразования регистра) имена, сравнивать их и, если не совпадают, переименовывать и сообщать об этом:

   ```
   $ comm -1 -2 \
   <(cd "$base"; find -mindepth 1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort) \
   <(cd "$ren"; find -mindepth 1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort) | \
   while read n; do \
    c1=$(cd "$base"; find -iwholename "$n"); \
    c2=$(cd "$ren"; find -iwholename "$n"); \
    if [[ "$c1" != "$c2" ]]; then \
     echo "переименовываем $ren/$c2 в $ren/$c1"; \
     mv "$ren/$c2" "$ren/$c1"; \
    fi; \
   done
   ```

   получаем:

   ```
   переименовываем 2/./sound в 2/./Sound
   переименовываем 2/./Sound/file в 2/./Sound/File
   ```

   а внутри каталога `2` — имена в нужном регистре:

   ```
   $ tree 2
   2
   └── Sound
       ├── File
       └── file3
   ```

---

итоговый скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash
base=$1
ren=$2
comm -1 -2 \
<(cd "$base"; find -mindepth 1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort) \
<(cd "$ren"; find -mindepth 1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort) | \
while read n; do
 c1=$(cd "$base"; find -iwholename "$n")
 c2=$(cd "$ren"; find -iwholename "$n")
 if [[ "$c1" != "$c2" ]]; then
  echo "переименовываем $ren/$c2 в $ren/$c1"
  mv "$ren/$c2" "$ren/$c1"
 fi
done
```

принимает два параметра — «базовый» и «переименовываемый» каталоги.